# Getting 404 error in Codeigniter Digital Ocean

Tags: php, codeigniter, digital-ocean

Hosted a Codeigniter App in ***Digital Ocean***. Getting 404 error after login.

`$config["base_url"] = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);`

`$config["index_page"] = "index.php";`

`$config["uri_protocol"]  = "REQUEST_URI";`

and htacess codes are

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: as you are removing index.php with .htaccess, it should be `$config["index_page"] = "";`

Comment: `http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])` What does it output?

Comment: Are you using which web server?

Comment: @Vickel Tried but same error occurs

Comment: @mail2bapi Apache

Comment: @Sreejithvs try with this
```RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]```

Comment: Issue solved. its happened because of mod_rewrite was not enabled @mail2bapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to Enable mod_rewrite . Refer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7